# MOOTOOLS variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, mootools, closures

I'm using mootools:
I can't figure out how to use a variable when using an addEvent.

I want to use a for next loop to set values in a loop:

```
for (x=0;x<num;x++){
var onclickText = 'function (){onclick="addPageMoveEvent('+x+'"); }';
$('pageNum'+x).addEvent('click', onclickText);
}
```

>

I've search forums but not found any help.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: First of all, `for (x=0;x<num;x++)` should be `for (var x=0;x<num;x++)`. That exact problem took me three hours to solve once.

Comment: don't understand the "var" issue.  I thought var was simply about scope of the variable ie global or not global.  Why does it make a difference?

Comment: Because if it's global and not enough care is taken, all invocations of this code will create references to `x`, causing every link to do the same. If `x` is local, its value is not preserved, i.e. references would be created to different things named `x`. But with the added complication of closures, it doesn't really matter anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The [addEvent](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvent) method in MooTools accepts two arguments:

```
myElement.addEvent(type, fn);
```

**Arguments:**

- type - (string) The event name to monitor ('click', 'load', etc) without the prefix 'on'.
- fn - (function) The function to execute.

It does not take a string and passing a string such as `"myFunction()"` or `"function() { myFunction(); }"` will not work.

Since you are inside a loop, and the variable `x` will share the environment, you need to wrap its value inside another closure. One way is to use an additional closure:

```
$("pagenum" + x).addEvent("click", (function(value) {
    return function() { addPageMoveEvent(value); }
})(x));
```

See all [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+closure+loops) on StackOverflow regarding this particular problem of creating closures within loops.

Also worth checking out is this MDC article - [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake)

Comment: Oops, I was used to jQuery that is more flexible. I'll update my answer. I like MooTools more than any other framework, but I increasingly feel it's rather rigid.

Comment: Thanks @MvanGuest :) I haven't seen [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or one of the shorthand functions such as [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in jQuery accepting a string of executable JavaScript code before to be honest.

Comment: Weird. I must have seen something like that somewhere, and MooTools and jQuery are the only frameworks I'm familiar with... If I find it, I'll tell you.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: this first example will not work! Read on for an explanation.**

You are confusing `onclick` HTML syntax with the MooTools `addEvent`. Try

```
for (var x=0;x<num;x++){
    $('pageNum'+x).addEvent('click', 'addPageMoveEvent('+x+');');
}
```

This is simpler and cleaner, but might still not do what you want. This code will call the function `addPageMoveEvent` every time the link is clicked... is that what you want?

**Since MooTools doesn't allow the above method, you *must* use the following:**

A programmatically more interesting and less hazardous way to do the same would be:

```
factory = function (x) { return function() { addPageMoveEvent(x); }; };
for (var x=0;x<num;x++){
    $('pageNum'+x).addEvent('click', factory(x));
}
```

This uses a factory for creating closures that hold your values of `x`... rather complex code, but it's the purist way. It also avoids using the scary `eval` that occurs because you feed `addEvent` a string. (It seems that MooTools doesn't like the other option anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the purists way and it work!! Thanks.  Can you confirm to me my understanding.  I think that it adds factory(0) factory(1) etc to the elements and then it calls that passing in the factory value as the x ?

Comment: If I understand that sentence correctly, yes. It calls `factory(1)` for example. `factory` executes and returns a function that, when executed, calls `addPageMoveEvent(1)`. Then this function is passed into the `addEvent` call. When the event fires, this function is called, which in turn makes the right `addPageMoveEvent` call. Essentially, `factory` is a function factory function that manufactures a function that calls another function passing on the ***value*** of the variable that was passed to the factory. ... Read over this a few times :) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That a use case for mootools pass method.

```
for (x=0;x<num;x++){
  $('pageNum'+x).addEvent('click', addPageMoveEvent.pass(x));
}
```

Pass internally creates a closure that holds x in the his scope, so when the click event is fired it has the right value cause its not the same from the for loop.